# auto-offset-reset=latest does not work in spring-kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a use case where I want the consumer to always start from the latest offset. I don't need to commit offsets for this consumer. This is not possible to achieve with spring-kafka, as a new consumer group always commits newly assigned partitions. Then, on subsequent starts of the program, the consumer reads from this stored offset, and not from the latest. In other words, only the very first start with a new consumer group behaves correctly, i.e. consuming from the latest. The problem is in `KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.onPartitionsAssigned()`

For reference, i set the following in spring boot

```
spring.kafka.listener.ack-mode=manual
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=latest
spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code was added to solve some nasty race conditions when a repartition occurred while a new consumer group started consuming; it could cause lost or duplicate records, depending on configuration.

It was felt best to commit the initial offset to avoid these conditions.

I agree, though, that if the user takes complete responsibility for offsets (with a MANUAL ackmode) then we should probably not do that commit; it's up to the user code to deal with the race (in your case, you don't care about lost records).

Feel free to open a GitHub issue (contributions are welcome).

In the meantime, you can avoid the situation by having your listener implement `ConsumerSeekAware` and seek to the topic/partition ends during assignment.

Another alternative is to use a UUID for the group.id each time; and you will always start at the topic end.